# Linux IIO device : How to configure interrupt register 0x3F of lis2dw12 vai sysfs?

Tags: linux, stm32, iio

I have an IIO device, lis2dw12 and I can read its raw value via sysfs calls. cat /sys/bus/../in_accel_x.raw etc.. for all the channels.

I want to enable interrupts now but I do not have sysfs attribute for it. How can one able to set a specific register of a IIO device vai user space sysfs calls.
Note I am able to set any register vai IIO_REG and debugfs but that is not intended for writing code. Also I do not have SPIDEV enabled.

How to read/configure a register of IIO device vai SYSFS or any other way.

Comment: You can't turn on interrupts unless there is an interrupt service routine configured to receive the interrupt. This must be in the kernel driver. Which driver is your device using?

Comment: @stark, I am using St kernel driver which is https://codebrowser.dev/linux/linux/drivers/iio/accel/st_accel_core.c.html

Comment: In IIO it's called _buffered mode_ in case driver supports it (I believe ST drivers support that).